# Best way to reuse where conditions with Codeigniter and Active Record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a controller that needs to run 4 or 5 datatabase queries all with the same basic where conditions. Since the conditions involve around a dozen if/else statements I'd like to avoid duplicating it within the model or re-running it 5 times if possible.

Is there an intelligent way to reuse the WHERE clauses from model function to function?

Comment: Could you post some of your code to see what do you have exactly?

Answer (score 5):

Use CI's [Active Record Caching](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#caching).

Example (verbatim from the linked page):

```
$this->db->start_cache();
$this->db->select('field1');
$this->db->stop_cache();

$this->db->get('tablename');

//Generates: SELECT `field1` FROM (`tablename`)

$this->db->select('field2');
$this->db->get('tablename');

//Generates: SELECT `field1`, `field2` FROM (`tablename`)

$this->db->flush_cache();

$this->db->select('field2');
$this->db->get('tablename');

//Generates: SELECT `field2` FROM (`tablename`)
```

`WHERE` clauses can be "cached" this way as well, so this should be what you need. If you must, move some cached AR calls into a function, and simply call the function at the beginning of each other function that needs it in your model. Each time you run a query, the cached functions will be called until you `flush_cache()`